# EF Querying DbContext of Generic type using its unique key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating a uni-directional sync which is I have 2 context (WebContext and StagingContext). Everytime I call `SaveChangesAsync()` it should sync the data updated on WebContext to StagingContext. Here's the following code I have:

**Attributes**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SyncEntityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Target { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
{
    await SyncEntityAsync(stagingContext, cancellation);

    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellation);
}

private async Task SyncEntityAsync<T>(T dbContext, CancellationToken cancellation = default) where T : DbContext
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x.Entity.GetType(), typeof(SyncEntityAttribute)) != null)
        .ToList();

    try
    {
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(entry.Entity.GetType(), typeof(SyncEntityAttribute)) as SyncEntityAttribute;
            if (attribute == null)
                continue;

            var uniqueKeys = entry.Properties.Where(x => x.Metadata.IsUniqueIndex()).ToList();

            var targetEntity = await GetQueryable(dbContext, attribute.TargetEntity); // Not yet implemented, I want this to return a single entity based on the generic type filtered by its unique key

            mapper.Map(entry.Entity, targetEntity);

            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    dbContext.Add(targetEntity);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    if (targetEntity.HasProperty("IsActive"))
                    {
                        targetEntity.TrySetProperty("IsActive", false);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I need to sync any entity model that has the `SyncEntity` attribute in it. I want to query the data on the StagingContext to see if it already exists or not. In order to do this, I need to query it by its `Target` attribute which is a Generic Type. If I am only querying using Primary Key then this would be easy since the DbContext has `FindAsync` method which allows to pass Generic Types. I want to do the same with `FindAsync` but this time I will be filtering it using the unique key which unique are get from `entry.Properties.Where(x => x.Metadata.IsUniqueIndex()).ToList();`

How can I achieve this? Looking for a solution like an extension method but I can't find any in the internet.

Update based on the suggested solution:

```
private static async Task<object> _GetQueryable<T>(DbContext dbContext, List<PropertyEntry> uniqueKeys)
    where T : class
{
    if (uniqueKeys is null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (uniqueKeys.Count <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var filters = new List<Expression>(uniqueKeys.Count);

    foreach (var key in uniqueKeys)
    {
        var wrapper = Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(key.CurrentValue.GetType()), key.CurrentValue));
        var value = Expression.Property(wrapper, "Value");
        filters.Add(Expression.Equal(p, value));
    }

    var body = filters.Aggregate((c, n) => Expression.AndAlso(c, n));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    return await dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}
```

This is my current solution for now, but executing the code `filters.Add(Expression.Equal(p, value));` throws an exception `The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'Web.Gateway.Core.StagingModels.User' and 'System.String'.`. It seems like it compared the unique key to the model and not on the model property.

**Update:** Final code that works

```
private static Task<object> GetQueryable(DbContext dbContext, Type entityType, List<PropertyEntry> uniqueKeys)
{
    return (Task<object>)typeof(SharedContext).GetMethod(nameof(_GetQueryable), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { dbContext, uniqueKeys });
}

private static async Task<object> _GetQueryable<T>(DbContext dbContext, List<PropertyEntry> uniqueKeys)
    where T : class
{
    if (uniqueKeys is null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (uniqueKeys.Count <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var entityType = typeof(T);
    var p = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
    var filters = new List<Expression>(uniqueKeys.Count);

    foreach (var key in uniqueKeys)
    {
        var wrapper = Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(key.CurrentValue.GetType()), key.CurrentValue));
        var value = Expression.Property(wrapper, "Value");
        filters.Add(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(p, entityType.GetProperty(key.Metadata.Name)), value));
    }

    var body = filters.Aggregate((c, n) => Expression.AndAlso(c, n));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    return await dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I'd ask though WHY you're trying to do this in this way? There seems a big risk of the data getting out of sync anyway if you have partially complete process (e.g. the first context saved, then the second part failed). If you're looking to write the data twice, there's likely some easier solutions...

Comment: @PhilS for now, I don't mind if the data is out of sync, I just want to make it sync to other databases

Comment: What EF Version are you using... when I copy your code with an EF 6.4 project, `entry.Properties` doesn't exist.

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver16 - this will allow you to easily, accurately and consistently sync data without any code changes.

Comment: @grek40 i am using EF 6.0.9 on NET6.0

Comment: @PhilS I am trying to sync some of the data and not as a whole that is why I am using its unique key rather than primary key

Comment: Assume you must be building out the update more? Anyway, I'll leave it at 'I probably would do something else' and try to answer the question. Bit confused why a PK would not uniquely identify a record? Anyway - the next logical step looks to be figuring out how many unique indexes you have in your list - if it's none, give up. If it's more than one, you either need to query them one by one, or pick First() and use that. Then use reflection to find the value of that unique field in the data you've passed in (e.g. UniqueId=1234) - you know what column you want to query, and have a filter value.

Comment: At this point you may need some dynamic SQL or dynamic linq - please check carefully for security concerns. Then you can run queries to get the matching records from your secondary context "select x,y,z from [ObjectName] where [uniqueId] = [value]".

Like I said, I probably wouldn't do this. An alternative would be to clone your repository layer in DI (one for prd, one for stg), and setup a layer above that (e.g. unitOfWork) that would handle sending the commands for both, and committing as a transaction.

Comment: So you use EF Core 6 and not EF? Would be good to make that clear in the tags.

Comment: Why not use replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic version of your method GetQueryable and call it through reflection:

```cs
private static Task<object> GetQueryable(DbContext dbContext, Type entityType, List<PropertyEntry> uniqueKeys)
{
    return (Task<object>)typeof(ApplicationContext).GetMethod(nameof(_GetQueryable), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { dbContext, uniqueKeys });
}
```

Then the generic version should create a predicate dynamically. Linq expression could be created with `Expression` class:

```cs
private static async Task<object> _GetQueryable<T>(DbContext dbContext, List<PropertyEntry> uniqueKeys)
    where T : class
{
    if (uniqueKeys is null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (uniqueKeys.Count <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var filters = new List<Expression>(uniqueKeys.Count);

    foreach (var key in uniqueKeys)
    {
        var property = Expression.Property(p, key.Metadata.PropertyInfo);
        var value = Expression.Constant(key.CurrentValue);
        filters.Add(Expression.Equal(property, value));
    }

    var body = filters.Aggregate((c, n) => Expression.AndAlso(c, n));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
    return await dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}
```

Depending of your expectations, you should rework your code to be more efficient.

Your entities are fetched one by one, maybe you should consider batching.

The call of `_GetQueryable<T>()` is done by reflection, you could consider it as a slow API (but the previous point is much important). A delegate could be created and cached for each entity type.

Generated expressions with usage of `Expression.Constant` will lead to non parameterized sql queries: internal cache of EF can grow (with many `CompiledQuery` instances) and causes some memory leaks. If your database is sqlserver, query execution plan will be different for each entity. You can create a wrapper arround the value, expose the value with a public property and replace the constant expression by a property expression:

```cs
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
//...
var wrapper = Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(key.CurrentValue.GetType()), key.CurrentValue));
var value = Expression.Property(wrapper, "Value");
```

Comment: please look at the updates